# Vim not breaking line when adding text at the beginning

Tags: vim, editor, text-editor

I set `textwidth=20` to have Vim break lines automatically and it works fine, like this:

> `1`  1234 1234 1234 1234 
>    `2`  1234 1234 1234 1234 
>    `3`  1234 1234 1234 1234

However, when I  go to the beginning of line 2 and add some text the line is not breaking, like this:

> `1`  1234 1234 1234 1234 
>    `2`  1234 1234 1234 1234 1234 1234 1234 1234 
>    `3`  1234 1234 1234 1234

Then I have to use `gqap` to correct the width which gives:

> `1`  1234 1234 1234 1234 
>    `2`  1234 1234 1234 1234 
>    `3`  1234 1234 1234 1234 
>    `4`  1234 1234 1234 1234

Is there any way to break lines automatically when adding text to the beginning of the line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is `auto-format`. See `:h auto-format`

```
:set formatoptions+=a
```

> When the 'a' flag is present in 'formatoptions' text is formatted
>   automatically when inserting text or deleting text.